# Dynamically Get "this" value based on a string variable Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 10.
In the following function, I would like to pass in filter variable and dynamically be able to use it as below so that ultimately I could get the startValue.

```
let filter = "AgeRange";

ValidateValues(endValue: string,filter:string){
startValue = this.SearchFields.{filter}.Start;  

}
```

SearchFields looks as follows:

```
export class SearchFilters{
    Gender: string = "Select";
    AgeRange:StartEndValues = new StartEndValues;
    CsaScore: StartEndValues = new StartEndValues;
    FarmSize: StartEndValues = new StartEndValues;
    PracticeCategory:string = "Select";

    public constructor(init?:Partial<SearchFilters>){
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}

export class StartEndValues{
    Start: string = "Select";
    End: string="Select";

    public constructor(init?:Partial<StartEndValues>){
        Object.assign(this,init)
    }
}
```

Comment: what class does `ValidateValues` belong to? What is `this.SearchFields`? Also, `this.SearchFields.{filter}` is not valid TS syntax, so it would be good to elaborate on what exactly you would like to achieve. Is it just `this.SearchFields[filter]` ?

Comment: All I'm looking for is correct syntax to use instead of this.SearchFields.{filter}.Start; If I call ValidateValues("10","AgeRange"); I expect startValue to be assigned the value of this.SearchFields.AgeRange.Start

Comment: yes, but `ValidateValues` looks like a definition of a class method, but we cannot see what that class is so there's missing context. Also, the variable `SearchFields` is not defined anywhere - or did you mean `SearchFilters` from the second code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this would be to store your filters as an Object, rather than as a class:

```
const searchFilters = {
  ageRange: StartEndValues = new StartEndValues(),
  csaScore: StartEndValues = new StartEndValues(),
  farmSize: StartEndValues = new StartEndValues(),
}
```

If you do it this way, you can then access the individual filter ranges using bracket accessor notation:

```
filter = "ageRange";
startValue = searchFilters[filter].start;
```

Check out the following page for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Aside from this specific problem, I would be very careful when storing things like filters with lots of different forms in a single class or object like that. Rather than storing the data in that class and then performing the filtering logic elsewhere, consider defining each of your filters as a pure function (with an identical signature for each filter).